# Sensing 24v AC with 4N35?

Tags: ac, opto-isolator

Basically I have sliding gate which has contacts to turn lamp when it's open or closed (two different ones) that are rated 24v AC max 3W.

I would like to use those contacts to know if the gate is open or closed. I'm a total newbie in electronics, googled a bit, and found that what I probably want to use is optocoupler.

And found a scheme like this:

[image: Circuit]

Explanations seem logical, I can get 4N45 at my local shop and for diode I would use 1N4148.

The thing is that I already have low amps (0.125) so will it be enough to drive the 4N35?

Comment: The 4N35 is a proportional optocoupler, the output current will be proportional to the input current. So what output current do you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: The absolute maximum rating for the input forward current is 50 mA.]

From the [datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/81181/4n35.pdf).

The 4N35 isn't rated for an input of more than 50 mA, 0.05 A. So if that's not enough for your application (the output current of a 4N35 is approximately equal to the input current, and also isn't rated for more than 50 mA continuous), it's not a good part for this application anyway. But I don't think you'll need more than that; that's quite a lot of current for a signal.

Comment: What got me confused is that 0.3mA . I mean is there a minimum optocoupler to work? And now that I look at it, afaik the diagram has maths wrong? Or am I missing something? I = V /R which is  (33 - 2) /10000 which is 0.003 amps which is 3 mA and not 0.3 mA ? And why is there a two, is their target voltage 2?

Comment: @gerasalus The 2 is the forward voltage of the diode. You are right, it would be 3 mA; the schematic you show has a mistake in it.

Comment: One more question, do you think that the 10k resistor in this scheme is in correct place with regards to optocoupler diode cathode ?

Comment: @gerasalus I don't see any problem with it.